# c# outlook instantiate Items collection to add items in loop

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I'm trying to create an application that moves items to a specific store/folder.
I can either look on a specific folder and using `folder.items` collect the items and then use a `foreach` loop to move them one by one. This part works ok.

But I would like also to add the items using the drag-drop Windows forms functionality.

The problem I have is that I cannot create and instantiate a collection of Items (zero items).
If I use null, the first time I try to add one `MailItem` it fails (**System.NullReferenceException:** 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
).
Also, I cannot leave the collection without a value because this will make the compiler to fail (Use of unassigned local variable).
I've tried to work with `List<Outlook.MailItem>` but then I don't know how to convert this into an Outlook Items collection.

This is the event that loops through the selection in the active explorer:

```
private void dataGridViewRules_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            Outlook.Application application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
            Outlook.Explorer explorer = application.ActiveExplorer();

            //instantiate
            Outlook.Items items = null;

            foreach (MailItem mailItem in explorer.Selection)
            {
                items.Add(mailItem);
            }

            //uses a reversed for loop and uses item.move to move each MailItem
            MoveMailItemsTest(items);
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I also tried to intantiate with  `new Outlook.Items()` but it doesn't work also.

Comment: can you share the code you are using that causes the failures. Also, please read up on why you get Null Reference Exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a standalone `Items` collection - `Items` object can only exist in the context of the parent folder (`MAPIFolder.Items`). But I am not sure why you declare your items variable above as `Items` instead of `List<MailItem>`. Is it only because your existing `MoveMailItemsTest()` method takes `Items` as a parameter? You woudl have to redesign that.

Comment: Yes, it is because of the method `MoveMailItemsTest`. Inside I can also use the `Items.Restrict` function and when geting Items from `Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(...) and Folder.Items`. I can either create a new method and work with `List<MailItem>` or I have to convert such a list to an `Items` collection. Your suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: You really need to take a new method or try to change your existing method to take an IEnumerable as a parameter instead of Items.

Comment: Does it means an `IEnumerable` can accept a `List<MailItem>` or an `Items` collection? If so, how can I then have a variable than can work with either options?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to cast both List<MailItem> and Items to IEnumerable

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually instantiated anything. Assigning null to a variable means it's a null reference. What you need is a constructor call.

Original suggestion was to try this:

```
var items = new List<MailItem>();
```

Which unfortunately didn't work because Outlook.Items is itself a collection class, and not well documented.

Upon reviewing the original code, my suggestion would be to avoid creating new variables altogether since it would just be new references to existing objects. Instead, pass the original objects directly to the helper method like so:

```
MoveMailItemsTest(explorer.Selection);
```

You really only need to loop through objects if you are going to manipulate, filter, etc. And even then, LINQ syntax will do most of that work for you (it's worth learning, trust me).

Comment: The compiler complains with 'cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List<Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem> to Office.Interop.Outlook.Items'

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a streamlined example which eliminates construction of a new collection altogether.

Comment: Even so, I still have to manage the explorer selection inside my method. Because I don't know how to take `Items` and `List<Outlook.MailItem>` and adapt it in the same method I'll create a new signature and treat both types os parameters separately (overloading).